# Determine whether the transformation is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

I have a linear transformation $Q : P_5 \to M_{2,3}$, given by

$$Q(a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 + a_4x^4 + a_5x^5) = \begin{bmatrix}a_0& a_1& a_2\\ a_5-a_4&a_5+a_4& a_3 \end{bmatrix}.$$

So I know that $Q$ has to be a one-to-one linear transformation of $P$ onto $M$ but where do I go from there? Is it not isomorphism because of $P_5$?

Comment: Isnn't being one to one and onto on a vector space precisely means it is an isomorphism? I don't think there is anything else for that.

Comment: Also, I don't think the RHS makes sense, I can't figure out the size of your matrix, it has uneven columns and rows. The first row has 3 elements, the last row has 1.

Comment: I fixed it, hawk. the first set of coordinates is the top, the second is the bottom. it's a 3x3.

Comment: the question says to explain my reasoning... would saying that Q is a one-to-one linear transformation of P onto M be enough? How would I start off to show that it is a linear transformation?

Comment: I think you have to find the matrix of transformation, then do the usual row reduction.

Comment: What is $P_5$? What is $M_{2,3}$?

Comment: P and M are isomorphic vector spaces

Comment: @will I formatted your matrix. Take a look at the edit history to see how. Revert, if necessary

Comment: I saw thank you that's how it's supposed to look

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the standard bases, the matrix of $Q$ is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 &0 & 0& 0&0 \\
0 & 1 &0 & 0& 0&0 \\
0 & 0& 1& 0& 0& 0\\
0 &0 & 0& 0& -1& 1\\
0 & 0& 0& 0& 1& 1\\
0 & 0& 0& 1& 0& 0\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

$Q$ represents an isomorphism iff this matrix is invertible

iff it has full rank

iff its null space is trivial

iff its determinant is nonzero... choose your preferred method.

Comment: so where does the P and M come into place?

Comment: @will They don't, once you fix bases for them. The theory of finite-dimensional vector spaces is "trivial" because fixing bases lets you identify any real vector space with some $\mathbb{R}^n$ and any linear map with some matrix.

Comment: You really have a couple things to add,eg which side your matrix is operating on the vectors, and how the output goes into the matrix. I can infer that you want to use the matrix on the left of column vectors, but maybe the op can't

Comment: @rschwieb I'm not sure I understand your confusion. The matrix I wrote down represents $Q$ in the basis $(1,x,\ldots,x^5)$ and the standard basis for matrix spaces. It acts on coordinate vectors on the left as usual. I assume the OP is familiar with the matrix representation of a linear map.

Comment: okay so I was able to invert it to {(1,0,0,0,0,0) , (0,1,0,0,0,0), (0,0,1,0,0,0), (0,0,0,0,0,1), (0,0,0,-1/2,1/2,0), (0,0,0,1/2,1/2,0)} so it is isomorphic?

Comment: @A.P. I am not confused. I am just saying the clarity could be improved. Regards

Comment: @rschwieb Fair enough, I agree.

Comment: @will The inverse matrix represents the inverse linear transformation of $Q$. Explicitly computing the inverse of $Q$ amounts to inverting the matrix, as you did. So yes, you can conclude that the inverse exists, i.e., that $Q$ is an isomorphism.